# Outputting an image in modx with phpthumbof and runsnippet()

Tags: php, modx, phpthumb

Within Modx Revolution, I'm trying to get phpthumb to work from within a snippet I'm writing - I think I have almost all the pieces, but I've a hunch that maybe I'm not formatting the image filepath correctly.

This is the code I have:

```
$input = "http://www.domain.com/assets/files/".$cover;
$width = 610;
$height = 504;
$options = "w=$width&h=$height&zc=1";  
$thumb = $modx->runSnippet("phpthumbof",array('input' => $input, 'options' => $options));
```

If I comment out the last line, the page loads without errors, but uncommented I get an error and nothing else:

> The image “http://www.domain.com/” cannot be displayed because it
>   contains errors.

But if I echo the value of $input, it *does* give the image URL, so I assume that phpthumb doesn't want a URI string...?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to change `$input = "http://www.domain.com/assets/files/".$cover;` to `$input = "assets/files/".$cover;` or input file placed on another domen?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The input file is on the same domain. I tried your suggestion - there are no errors this time, but it still doesn't output a filepath.

Comment: https://github.com/modxcms/phpthumbof/ - phpThumbOf is official depriciatated. Use pthumb or phpthumbsup instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware; thanks. I received a solution, on the ModX forum, to my initial problem.